# Threading in Python and global variables - difference between arrays and standard variables?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, global

I currently try to write a bigger python program using threading and encountered the problem that arrays do not have to be declared as global somehow.

```
import numpy as np
import threading
import time
import ctypes
import multiprocessing
import random
import os


def child1():
    #global var
    starttime = time.time()
    for ite in range(10):
        #data_np[ite] = time.time()-starttime
        #print data_np[ite]
        var += 1
        print var
        time.sleep(1)

def child2():
    #global var
    for ite in range(10):
        #print data_np
        print var
        print "\n"
        time.sleep(1)


os.system("clear")
data_np = np.zeros(shape=(10), dtype="float")
var = 0

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=child1)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=child2)

thread1.start()
thread2.start()

thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

The code stated as above will produce an error message since var isn't declared as a global variable. Uncommenting

```
global var
```

produces an executable script printing the value of var twice. 
But when using the numpy array data_np, no declaration

```
global data_np
```

is needed. The script will run nevertheless.
I don't understand this behavior. Can somebody give an explanation to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `global` statement is required to inform Python that you want a variable (`var` in this case) to be treated as a global, universally modifiable name rather than a local variable for each of your functions. You would fare marginally better if you moved your `var = 0` definition above the functions:

But as [Marcin says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31550624/240490), "For the love of god don't do this." Getting around a few `NameError`s isn't the key issue here. Global variables are difficult to manage in many programs, even without concurrency. In a concurrent environment, they become nightmares. Their behavior is also very different in threaded vs. multiprocessing concurrency (both of which you've imported, though you seem to be using threading at present), and across different platforms (Windows works differently than Unix/Linux/Mac OS X, e.g.).

The reason your array reference works, at least somewhat, is that the internal contents of global structures (e.g. dictionaries, lists, NumPy arrays) are readily modifiable even when the structure as a whole is not. Most of that has to do with how Python manages names (roughly speaking, "variables") and not really so much with concurrency. But in a concurrent environment, modifications to those global structures is going to get dicey (read: confusing, unreliable, not easily reproducible) very quickly.

So, long story short, there are easily three or four overlapping issues here before we even begin to discuss the [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) your threads face.

You might be able to get basically working code if your reader (`child2`) had a longer sleep time than your writer (`child1`). But beware: For anything except a toy example, you'll need a genuinely concurrency-aware structure (e.g. [a queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It gives a nice first insight to the underlying structure.

Comment: Maybe to make things more clear, the code was just an example to clarify the problem I encountered with arrays and standard variables being treated differently. In my main program, I want to create two processes, where one does some plotting and the other one contains two threads. One thread for communicating with an external device and the other one for dealing with user input. I try to avoid concurrency by having only variables or arrays written to by only one process or thread, respectively. Up to now, this worked out under OSX.

Comment: Yes. If you only write to a structure from one thread, that greatly simplifies things. Because of "race conditions," it doesn't mean you will get 100% reliable results. For those, you need truly concurrency aware structures, such as queues. For simple demonstrations, you can sometimes get away without using them.

Answer (score 0):

1. `global` is used to allow assigment to a global variable. You can read a global variable which is not shadowed without this declaration.
2. For the love of god don't do this. Read about techniques for managing concurrency.